# Angular 2 and super ng-table

Tags: angular

I am trying to integrate ng2-super-table into my angular2 application.
I used the github for my source code:
https://github.com/andyperlitch/ng2-super-table

The problem is that the directive tag is depracated in ES5.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'demo-app',
  directives: [SuperTable]
  .
  .
});
```

I searched on the Internet and it seems that i need to add the directive into declarations of the module like this:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule],
    declarations: [GridComponent, SuperTable],
    exports: [GridComponent]
})
```

The problem is that I still receive this error:
Can't bind to 'tableclasses' since it isn't a known property of 'super-table'.

I mention the fact that I am new to angular2.

Can you please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/andyperlitch/ng2-super-table/issues/3

This component is not yet compatible with Angular2 >= 2.0.0